# LibGDX JDBC path

Tags: java, libgdx

just a quick question to inlcuding library into IntelliJ IDEA using LibGDX tool.
There is a directory called libs which is used for external libraries, right? I pushed my downloaded library into and executetd "add library". It worked as u can see in the picture.
[added library + sql code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tVxv.png)

When I wanna use it, library isn't found. I also refreshed Gradle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson please read this question again, this is not the same issue that you marked as solution.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, you are right, the supposed dublication isnt really helpfull to solve my issue. (Maybe may question was not really well written - sry guys, i am not a native English speaker) So, could you please re-open my question till i've got a solution @Jarrod?

Comment: @Ah3n0bar6us don't worry, if my answer don't fix your problem. I'll reopen it.

Comment: I wanted to up vote it but i am an insignificant guy here and my vote isn´t shown ^^ Furthermore, shouldn´t he delete the wrong dublicate information?

Comment: Why can't you just include the source, or better yet is it on maven or any repo?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to compile your jar, Add dependency in your `build.gradle` file or android app module.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Refresh all gradle project and build.

**EDIT**

As your required jar **mysql-connector-java**, version **5.1.41** available in maven repository so it's better to inject your dependency through maven artifact.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.41'
}
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks a lot. i have red it in the internet as well, but in my build.gradle there is no dependencies, yet. So i dont know where to add this code =(

Comment: make `dependencies { }` at the end of build.gradle of android module and add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` inside dependencies.

Comment: It seems to do sth =D You've got the right answer. I am not connected yet but there is no above mentioned exeption anymore. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hey Abhishek, I need to say sorry. I thogth it would work, but it doesn't. I tried a lot, downloaded the package again but i always get the error: unsupported class file version 52.0 when I use the Driver class. =(

Comment: That is an error with the jar compatibility, not with the answer.

Comment: you are right. My question, how to add a library using libgdx is answered :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help Abishek. I've tried it but still the same error. Furthermore, I have checked my Maven JRE and JDK setting in Importing and Runner if they are equal. I tried it with 1.0.0.112 and 1.8.0.131.